# Why is using Task.Run() still blocking my UI?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a synchronous method I am calling with Task.Run() and my UI is being blocked and unresponsive. The method loads information from a database via COM Interop and I don't have any control over that.

```
public List<EdmAddInInfo2> GetInstalledAddins()
{
    IEdmAddInMgr7 addinMgr = m_vault as IEdmAddInMgr7;
    Array installedAddins = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(EdmAddInInfo2), 0);
    addinMgr.GetInstalledAddIns(out installedAddins);
    if (installedAddins?.Length > 0)
        return installedAddins.OfType<EdmAddInInfo2>().ToList();
    return null;
}
```

I am calling the method this way when my form is shown;

```
private async void LicensesForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    var m_addins = await GetInstalledAddins().ConfigureAwait(false);
    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = $"Loaded {m_addins.Count} addins.";
}

private async Task<List<EdmAddInInfo2>> GetInstalledAddins()
{
    AddinManager addinMgr = new AddinManager(Vault);
    var addins = await Task.Run(() => addinMgr.GetInstalledAddins()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return addins;
}
```

Usually I would use a BCW and be on my way, but I figured I would give Tasks a shot. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling GetInstalledAddins() from your UI thread?

Comment: I am, yes. It's called from LicensesForm_Shown(), as shown above.

Comment: For grins, return an empty list in GetInstalledAddins().  Maybe the constructor is the thing that's taking forever to load and blocking your UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method loads information from a database via COM Interop and I don't have any control over that.

Well then, depending on the implementation of that method, it may not be *possible* to unblock the UI thread.

However, you could try this: if that type is allocating COM objects in its constructor, they may be getting tied to the UI thread. I would try creating the instance on the background thread:

```
private Task<List<EdmAddInInfo2>> GetInstalledAddins()
{
  return Task.Run(() => new AddinManager(Vault).GetInstalledAddins());
}
```

> Usually I would use a BCW and be on my way

`BackgroundWorker` would have the exact same problem.

Comment: And BackgroundWorker has the same problem as well. Your answer led me to a fix and that is creating a new vault object in the GetInstalledAddins method. Thanks. (Awesome blog!)

Answer (score 3):

After the discussion in comments, I'm thinking that there is something deeper going on involving COM. One thing to be aware of when involving COM is that it uses the Dispatcher for receiving events, which has bitten me before. If the issue is related to COM one would probably need more information about what is going on and that digging might not be worthwhile. I wish I could be more helpful, but I think I'll have to default to advising the easy way out. Launch a thread to call GetInstalledAddins, assign the result to a local variable, and notify the UI of completion through the Dispatcher.

Also, from my original answer before editing to add the above,

```
var m_addins = await GetInstalledAddins().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

should be:

```
var m_addins = await GetInstalledAddins().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

This is because on the next line you assign to a UI element's Text property. This assignment must be done from the UI thread, which is active when you call `GetInstalledAddins()`, but because you then call `ConfigureAwait(false)` the execution continues after `await` on any thread the async manager (I forget what it's called) chooses.

One of the strengths of using `async`/`await` in UI code is that execution can (in normal situations) be resumed on the same thread the `await` call was made on. This way you can continue accessing UI objects after the `await`. But your call to `ConfigureAwait(false)` instructs the `async`/`await` engine that you don't care which thread the execution is resumed on (but in this case you really should care that the execution is resumed on the same thread).

Comment: Additionally, you probably don't need to call ConfigureAwait at all, it should resume execution on the same thread by default if possible. There may be a way to change the default that I don't know about, but whenever I await I do not call ConfigureAwait and I always get the UI thread back after using await (if the await is on the UI thread to begin with).

Comment: Removing ConfigureAwait or using ConfigureAwait(true) doesn't make a difference. The application isn't crashing; GetInstalledAddins does return what I expect it to and carries on. I read about ConfigureAwait here (http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), which lead me down this path.

Comment: Stephen Cleary's blog is an excellent resource for learning about async await, but since you are doing an asyncronous `await' rather than calling the asyncronous `Task.Result' (or `Task.Wait()') the issue he discusses in that post does not apply.

Comment: I can't edit my comments yet, but I meant "since you are doing an asyncronous `await` rather than calling the synchronous `Task.Result`..."

Comment: also, if you're not getting a crash then your await call must not be resuming. I just noticed that you're involving COM... COM is notorious for using the Dispatcher for events, I'm thinking something more complicated could be going on here. You might have to just go with using a thread and calling back through the dispatcher if you don't know what is going on in the COM code.

Comment: That's probably likely. The application runs fine, it's just that the UI is blocked on the addinMgr.GetInstalledAddIns(out installedAddins) line. (Where the work is actually being done.) I can Task.Delay there instead and all is well. I appreciate you taking the time to answer. +1

Comment: You're welcome. COM is old and from before threading was a common thing, so it can have unexpected issues with anything asyncronous. In one of my projects I had to sandbox a COM library in a separate console application because I was missing events whenever the UI was busy. I suppose I might have been able to somehow get a second dispatcher but the separate application was something I'd done before so it made sense for me.

Comment: @ehcanadian: The point of that blog post is *not* "use ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere". The point of that blog post is "don't block on async code".

Comment: Point taken. I'm learning, so at this/that point, Tasks are the nails and ConfigureAwait was my hammer. ;)